# mac-osx 10.9.4 Hadoop 2.7.1 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, macos, hadoop, hadoop2

When trying to run namenode -format, I am getting below error. Can anyone please suggest how to resolve it? ( On mac os x 10.9.4 version. Hadoop 2.7.1 version)

```
Pro:hadoop-2.7.1 hadoop$ bin/hdfs namenode -format
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/NameNode : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Java Version is as below...

```
Pro:hadoop-2.7.1 hadoop$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

In hadoop-env.sh path given as

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: Thanks you for editing to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**51 Major version of Java class file format conforms to Java 7.**

The Hadoop library in your version require Java 7, but you try to run it on Java 6 runtime which will not work.

Comment: Thank you very much ,I got it. Thanks!